# How do I set a function to run on exit in fish shell?

Tags: events, exit, fish

I want to do some cleanup before my shell script exits, including when it's cancelled with Ctrl-C.

I tried this code (in a `script.fish` file):

```
function exit_handler --on-event fish_exit
    echo exiting!
end

sleep 5 &
sleep 4 &
wait
```

If I let this code run normally, the `exit_handler` function is called as expected, but if I interrupt it with Ctrl-C, `exiting!` is not printed. Is there some way to always run the event handler, even if the script is aborted?

I'm using fish 3.4.0 on macOS 12.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not yet possible to trap control-C (SIGINT) in non-interactive scripts. This is a known limitation. See https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/6649